# How can I change the Alpha channel of a button in IOS without affecting the Text?

Tags: uibutton, ios7, uistoryboard

I have a couple of buttons in IOS7 with the background Alpha channel set to .5 (so the image behind them is somewhat visible). The only drawback is the text on the button face also becomes dim. I tried using a `UIView` under the button and setting it's alpha to .5; this works, but is sort of cobbled together. Also, managing the constraints for both items gets a bit tedious. Is there a way to keep the background Alpha setting low yet have the button text nice and bright/crisp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done without too much work using `CoreGraphics`. Here is the class that I've made to do just this. (I've named it `SODimButton` as an example for this answer.) The posted code here can also be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rcdilorenzo/6979461).

### SODimButton.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SODimButton : UIButton

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *buttonColor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *selectedButtonColor;

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat backgroundAlpha;

@end
```

### SODimButton.m

```
#import "SODimButton.h"

@implementation SODimButton

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // More drawing can be done if you get the context.
    // I actually don't use it in this example.
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (self.selected || self.highlighted) {
        [[self.selectedButtonColor colorWithAlphaComponent:self.backgroundAlpha] setFill];
    } else {
        [[self.buttonColor colorWithAlphaComponent:self.backgroundAlpha] setFill];
    }
    UIRectFill(rect);
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    [super setSelected:selected];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

…and here's how you would use it in a controller:

### MyViewController.m (in `viewDidLoad`)

```
SODimButton *button = [[SODimButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2 - 100, 50, 200, 44)];
[button setTitle:@"My Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.buttonColor = [UIColor redColor];
button.selectedButtonColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.73f green:0.10f blue:0.00f alpha:1.00f];
button.backgroundAlpha = 0.2f;
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

All of this code I've put into [this link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20180054/Stack%20Overflow/SODimButton.zip) (at least for a little while) for easy testing and experimentation. Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

After a couple days, couldn't figure it out so I just added a label over the top of the translucent button, along with some constraints to keep it lined up with the button for rotations.

Comment: You could create a more-transparent image and set it to be the background or subclass `UIButton` and create the background with `CoreGraphics`. I don't think the label over the top is quite the cleanest solution.

Comment: The problem with doing it in `CoreGraphics` is that it quickly becomes unwieldy code as you need to add supporting views, widgets and constraints and possibly other overhead such as font support which is much, much easier to do in Storyboards. It's the whole reason Apple is putting so much effort into Storyboards; to clean up the mess associated with managing all the CG widgets in code.

Comment: I'll add an answer that explains how to do this. It isn't really all that complicated.

Comment: Not all that complicated after all. Thanks for the reply!